# 3d product view with dynamic picturemap in Flash

Tags: flash, 3d, bitmap

A potential client of mine has asked whether it is possible to have a complete 3d rotating view of a product shown in flash that has an uploaded picture dynamically wrapped around it.

Let's take a winebottle as an example. The winebottle would be 'static' but the label could be uploaded. This should then be shown wrapped around the winebottle and be shown in a 3d rotating view.

Is todays Flash technology capable of such a concept?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few 3D libraries for Flash that can help you achieve this affect.  It's not as fast and fluid as OpenGL or other hardware-accelerated technologies, but you can still get pretty good results.  Check out the following:

Sandy3D: http://www.flashsandy.org/
Papervision: http://blog.papervision3d.org/

Flash 10 also added some rudimentary 3D tools into the flash player, but I don't think they get at what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if flash supports 3d rendering, if it doeds all you need is a 3d model of the winebottle and use the uploaded image as a texture.

If it doesn't you need to somewhat scale the uploaded image and run some kind of imagemanipulation algorithm (similar to a photoshop filter) to make it look like it's wrapped around the bottle, this would be rather limited though in terms of looking realistic.

Edit: And you would of course need to run the above algorithm for every frame if the bottle has been rotated